# Is it possible for there to be multiple labels to emails in gmail?

Tags: gmail, gmail-labels, gmail-filters

If an email applies to more than one filter (with associated label) will the email display all the labels for the relevant filters?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, it will display all that apply.

For each filter you're able to assign one label. If you happen to have multiple filters catch the same email, they will each label the incoming mail accordingly.

Comment: but it works... some of the times. Funny enough the autocomplete for contact groups does not work as well.